# R: slicing over dates in a dataframe using custom time window

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, slice

I have a dateframe of player rankings over many years (2000-2020), which looks like :
[image]

Now, I wish to `group_by()` and `summarise()` and calculate statistics for different time slices. One way is to use custom start and end dates to subset the date, like:

```
dataSubset = filter(data, rankingDate >="2000-01-01" & rankingDate <="2002-01-01")
dataSubset %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  summarise(
    avg_pts = mean(points)
  )
```

to get the average ranking points for each player in the 2-year period between Jan-1,2000 and Jan-1,2002.

Now, this is fine for a single slice of the data. But what I want are multiple slices over the entire dataset with a `startDate`, an `endDate`, and a `period` value, like:

```
dataSubsets = filter[data, rankingDate, startDate:endDate:period]
```

so that I could divide up the full 20-year period into, say, ten 2-year periods, and then calculate statistics for each 2-year period.

I don't want to copy-paste. What is the solution?

---

EDIT:
An example of the data I am using can be found here: https://github.com/JeffSackmann/tennis_atp/blob/master/atp_rankings_00s.csv

Do:

```
data <- read_csv("data/atp/atp_rankings_00s.csv")
data = data %>% 
  mutate(rankingDate = ymd(ranking_date) ) %>% 
  select(-ranking_date)
```

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducible example, preferably using `dput`, so we can assist with this question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `lubridate` and the intervals functionality, we can divide with the period of interest, like so:

```r
data %>%
  #' consider each player separately
  group_by(player) %>% 
  #' treat every second year as one group
  group_by(
    year_id = lubridate::interval(
      start = min(rankingDate),
      end = rankingDate
    ) %/% (2 * dyears()),
    .add = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    n_obs = n(),
    avg_points_pr_player = mean(points)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

This is for the 2 years period, where each players' points are averaged.

Comment: This isn't working. I added more details to my question. Please take a look.